Cannot get correct output in PSpice with the Buck Converter PSpice Transient Model from TI
I obtained the LM76005-Q1 transient model from the Texas Instrument website and imported it to PSpice. The website also provides a Design Calculator software, so I basically use it to determine other components' values and also cross-check with Webench-Circuit-Designer, and everything seems to fit with the datasheet information. However, I cannot get the correct output voltage after the transient analysis no matter what I do.
This is my schematic:

This is the analysis setting:

This is the output:

The output is supposed to reach 36V.
For the importing process, I unzipped the folder, used the Model Editor to export the .olb file, added the library to the schematic, edited the model, and associated it with the .lib file. I am a beginner, so maybe the problem is as simple as that I imported the model incorrectly? Could anyone please show me what I missed? I have been stuck for some time and don't know what or where to look at.
